# How to get the x,y coordinates of a offset spline from a x,y list of points and offset distance

Tags: python, graphics, offset, curve, spline

I need to make an offset parallel enclosure of an airfoil profile curve, but I cant figure out how to make all the points be equidistant to the points on the primary profile curve at desired distance.

**this is my example airfoil profile**
[image]

**this is my best and not good approach**
[image]

**EDIT** @Patrick Solution for distance 0.2
[image]

Comment: How do you store the current curve? Is it a list of **int** (x, y)? What accuracy of the result do you need?

Comment: @IlyaPeterov the curve is stored in np.array with x,y coordinates, I don't need much accurate result, just approximate curve will be fine, because I need this to make a finite element mesh between this two profile

Comment: The delta should be from the midpoint of each segment.  Let me add an example.

Comment: @PatrickMaupin I would greatly appreciate the example

Comment: I don't have your points so I can't do it exactly, but I have done an offset from a sine wave.  Turns out you also have to deal with the direction of the vector.

Comment: @PatrickMaupin an example list of points can be like this [data file](http://m-selig.ae.illinois.edu/ads/coord_seligFmt/ah79100c.dat), but for an example any list of points can be useful

Comment: I have updated the answer with a new sign calculation.

Comment: I added a cheesy example function that rounds the envelope around the pointy end of the wing.

Comment: Could you please give me the airfoil profile data? I made my solution yesterday, but there already was a working one, so I didn't post it, but I'd like to check if it works anyway.

Comment: my points are in here. [here](https://mega.nz/#!rYhVkQwJ!ulpz-9SNcOnhf1h5E_GlO8OqewWlc3HogcA6BZnDUZQ) but seem to be my mistake on some point because now works fine. I try this yesterday too late, you can dismiss my edit. thanks again

Comment: @IlyaPeterov your solution works?

Comment: @efirvida Yes, but not as good as Patrick's. It doesn't have have a semicircle and is a little inaccurate in general. Though it was a good exercise for me, thank you.

Comment: @IlyaPeterov thank to you for the effort

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You'll have to special-case slopes of infinity/zero, but the basic approach is to use interpolation to calculate the slope at a point, and then find the perpendicular slope, and then calculate the point at that distance.

I have modified the example from [here](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/simple_plot.html) to add a second graph.  It works with the [data file you provided](http://m-selig.ae.illinois.edu/ads/coord_seligFmt/ah79100c.dat), but you might need to change the sign calculation for a different envelope.

**EDIT** As per your comments about wanting the envelope to be continuous, I have added a cheesy semicircle at the end that gets *really close* to doing this for you.  Essentially, when creating the envelope, the rounder and more convex you can make it, the better it will work. Also, you need to overlap the beginning and the end, or you'll have a gap.

Also, it could almost certainly be made more efficient -- I am not a numpy expert by any means, so this is just pure Python.

```
def offset(coordinates, distance):
    coordinates = iter(coordinates)
    x1, y1 = coordinates.next()
    z = distance
    points = []
    for x2, y2 in coordinates:
        # tangential slope approximation
        try:
            slope = (y2 - y1) / (x2 - x1)
            # perpendicular slope
            pslope = -1/slope  # (might be 1/slope depending on direction of travel)
        except ZeroDivisionError:
            continue
        mid_x = (x1 + x2) / 2
        mid_y = (y1 + y2) / 2

        sign = ((pslope > 0) == (x1 > x2)) * 2 - 1

        # if z is the distance to your parallel curve,
        # then your delta-x and delta-y calculations are:
        #   z**2 = x**2 + y**2
        #   y = pslope * x
        #   z**2 = x**2 + (pslope * x)**2
        #   z**2 = x**2 + pslope**2 * x**2
        #   z**2 = (1 + pslope**2) * x**2
        #   z**2 / (1 + pslope**2) = x**2
        #   z / (1 + pslope**2)**0.5 = x

        delta_x = sign * z / ((1 + pslope**2)**0.5)
        delta_y = pslope * delta_x

        points.append((mid_x + delta_x, mid_y + delta_y))
        x1, y1 = x2, y2
    return points

def add_semicircle(x_origin, y_origin, radius, num_x = 50):
    points = []
    for index in range(num_x):
        x = radius * index / num_x
        y = (radius ** 2 - x ** 2) ** 0.5
        points.append((x, -y))
    points += [(x, -y) for x, y in reversed(points)]
    return [(x + x_origin, y + y_origin) for x, y in points]

def round_data(data):
    # Add infinitesimal rounding of the envelope
    assert data[-1] == data[0]
    x0, y0 = data[0]
    x1, y1 = data[1]
    xe, ye = data[-2]

    x = x0 - (x0 - x1) * .01
    y = y0 - (y0 - y1) * .01
    yn = (x - xe) / (x0 - xe) * (y0 - ye) + ye
    data[0] = x, y
    data[-1] = x, yn
    data.extend(add_semicircle(x, (y + yn) / 2, abs((y - yn) / 2)))
    del data[-18:]

from pylab import *

with open('ah79100c.dat', 'rb') as f:
    f.next()
    data = [[float(x) for x in line.split()] for line in f if line.strip()]

t = [x[0] for x in data]
s = [x[1] for x in data]


round_data(data)

parallel = offset(data, 0.1)
t2 = [x[0] for x in parallel]
s2 = [x[1] for x in parallel]

plot(t, s, 'g', t2, s2, 'b', lw=1)

title('Wing with envelope')
grid(True)

axes().set_aspect('equal', 'datalim')

savefig("test.png")
show()
```

Comment: in your code `x2, x1`, and `y2, y1` are two consecutive points in the airfoil profile?? so i have to iterate from `x[0]` to `x[len(x)-1]` ??

Comment: Yes, but that would only give you the same number of points as your original curve.  You may even want to interpolate more points to make your other curve smoother, since it's longer than your first curve.

Comment: @efirvida  Also, you probably want to start your delta from the midpoint of the line segment, because the tangent is known more closely there, e.g. `(x1 + x2) / 2, (y1 + y2) / 2`

Comment: I update my post with your solution and my set of points, works great!!, now need to close the open offset profile, can I do this wit curve fitting solution or something like that?

Comment: @efirvida Did you try my very latest change?  It seems to work with matplotlib with the data you provided.

Comment: Now works even better, but steel opened at the end, I know that if for don't have data to calculate the rest of the profile, as in my last comment can I approximate this with fitting curve?

Comment: Coming to a point doesn't work too well.  When creating the envelope, I would back up a tiny bit on the original data, and perhaps make a tiny semi-circle.  The rounder and more convex you can make it, the better it will work.  Also, you need to overlap the beginning and the end, or you'll have a gap.

Comment: Nice Job thanks a lot!!. I did a final update of mi post. looks pretty

Answer (score 6):

If you are willing (and able) to install a third-party tool, I'd highly recommend the [Shapely](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Shapely) module. Here's a small sample that offsets both inward and outward:

```
from StringIO import StringIO
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import requests
import shapely.geometry as shp

# Read the points    
AFURL = 'http://m-selig.ae.illinois.edu/ads/coord_seligFmt/ah79100c.dat'
afpts = np.loadtxt(StringIO(requests.get(AFURL).content), skiprows=1)

# Create a Polygon from the nx2 array in `afpts`
afpoly = shp.Polygon(afpts)

# Create offset airfoils, both inward and outward
poffafpoly = afpoly.buffer(0.03)  # Outward offset
noffafpoly = afpoly.buffer(-0.03)  # Inward offset

# Turn polygon points into numpy arrays for plotting
afpolypts = np.array(afpoly.exterior)
poffafpolypts = np.array(poffafpoly.exterior)
noffafpolypts = np.array(noffafpoly.exterior)

# Plot points
plt.plot(*afpolypts.T, color='black')
plt.plot(*poffafpolypts.T, color='red')
plt.plot(*noffafpolypts.T, color='green')
plt.axis('equal')
plt.show()
```

And here's the output; notice how the 'bowties' (self-intersections) on the inward offset are automatically removed:
[image]